# How to see all letters in the alphabet printed when running this?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int count[26] = {0};
    char str[100];

    printf("Ord: ");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    printf("Frekvens: \n");

    while (str[i] != '\0'){
        if (str[i]>= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){
            int x = str[i] -'a';
            count[x]++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++){
        printf("'%c' : %d\n", i + 'a', count[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to see all letters in the alphabet printed when running this? Something to do with the for loop?

Comment: Your second loop, where you print the frequencies, should not iterate over the string; it should iterate over the 26 letters.

Comment: Keep in mind that `scanf` with `"%s"` will stop at the first whitespace it encounters, so if you want to use more than one word you'll need to change your format string or use something like `fgets` to get the whole line.

Comment: BTW, you can use `islower()` instead of comparing with `a` and `z`.

Answer (score 0):

The printing loop should iterate over the indexes of `count`.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        printf("'%c' : %d\n", i + 'a', count[i]);
    }
```